# Shorter Date Interval results in longer execution time

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have this query:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*) AS 'RedactedCount'
    ,s.Redacted1
    ,s.[Redacted2]
    ,s.[Redacted3] AS 'Redacted3'
FROM RedactedTable1 s
    LEFT OUTER JOIN RedactedTable2 g ON s.Redacted5= g.Redacted5
WHERE g.Redacted6= 31013 AND s.DateTime >= '2013-03-02 00:00:00'
GROUP BY s.Redacted1,s.Redacted2, s.Redacted3
```

Which have a very odd behavior. This query takes a whole 1min30secs to complete. Should I change de date to 2013-04-02 00:00:00 (today as I'm writing this post), it is near instant, which is the expected behavior.

But if I change the date to 2013-02-02 (a 2 months time span instead of 1), the query takes only 20 secs.

Does Anyone has encountered this problem ? I am completely stunned on the result. It will also be an important SQL request of a web application that I am working on.

- Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio     **11.0.3128.0**
- Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC)    **6.1.7601.17514**
- Microsoft MSXML **3.0 6.0**
- Microsoft Internet Explorer **9.0.8112.16421**
- Microsoft .NET Framework **4.0.30319.296**
- Système d'exploitation **6.1.7601**

Note: The database is poorly designed, and contains absolutely no indexes. Yes, this is bad. Unfortunately, this is a commercial software and I have no rights to make changes on the database model. However, I do not think that the problem I have is caused by this.

P.S.: Sorry if my query is heavily redacted as I am on a strict NDA. I tried to made it as readable as possible.

Thanks !

Comment: are we talking of the select time (on sql server) or of the display time in MSIE (sql + iis + local render) ?

Comment: First of all, it is pointless to put a predicate condition on a table on the outer side of an outer join.  As soon as you do this, all rows in the final result set that do not have a match in that table are eliminated, effectively making the overall query behave as though it was an inner join.

Comment: tschmit007 : I am talking about execution time

Comment: What happens if you add `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` to the query? Depending on the amount of data you may be subject to `parameter sniffing` - a term you could search for and learn a whole lot more about than I could ever relay in a comment.

Comment: Aaron Bertrand: OPTION(RECOMPILE) did nothing to shorten the query. However, I went on (http://blogs.technet.com/b/mdegre/archive/2012/03/19/what-is-parameter-sniffing.aspx) and read the article. Good Read. Using dummy variables solved the issue. If you wish to submit an answer I'll accept it, as parameter Sniffing indeed was the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aaron Bertrand got the answer in a comment.

This problem was caused by parameter sniffing done by MSSQL.

Declaring and using dummy variables prevents MSSQL to falsely optimize the query using past optimizations.

The following link helped me learn about parameter sniffing http://blogs.technet.com/b/mdegre/archive/2012/03/19/what-is-parameter-sniffing.aspx

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it is pointless to put a predicate condition on a table on the outer side of an outer join. As soon as you do this, all rows in the final result set that do not have a match in that table are eliminated, effectively making the overall query behave as though it was an inner join.

The condition on RedactedTable2.Redacted6 should be part of the join conditions if you want the join to include rows where there is no matching row in table RedactedTable2.

```
 SELECT COUNT(*) AS 'RedactedCount',
     s.Redacted1, s.[Redacted2],
     s.[Redacted3] AS 'Redacted3'
 FROM RedactedTable1 s
      LEFT JOIN RedactedTable2 g 
          ON g.Redacted5= s.Redacted5
             And g.Redacted6= 31013 
 WHERE s.DateTime >= '2013-03-02 00:00:00'
 GROUP BY s.Redacted1,s.Redacted2, s.Redacted3
```

As to why the difference in performance, my suspicion is that your issue is caused by something in the data in the tables that is causing the query processor to use a different execution plan in one case than it was in the other.  This can easily happen.  If the optimizer "guesses" that it would need to examine more than a certain percentage of data rows using one query execution plan, based on database statistics about the distribution of data values in the tables), then it will switch to a different plan. 
Run both queries with the ShowPlan option turned on, and look and see what the differences are.

Comment: Thank you for the insight. The changes indeed made an impact. (2013-02-02 00:00:00 now runs under 10 seconds). However, the problematic date (2013-03-02 00:00:00) still completed in 2min22. Unfortunately I don't have access to the execution plan, and I'm pretty sure I can't either. You have sent me to on a good track though. So thank you very much !

Comment: I am talking to my SysAdmin if he can give me the "SHOWPLAN" permission on the database. Once I will be able to confirm that the request is using a different execution plan I will mark your answer as the accepted one...

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what Charles suggested you might ask the database administrator (assuming you have one) to run `UPDATE STATISTICS` on at least RedactedTable1 and RedactedTable2.  `UPDATE STATISTICS` requires you to have `ALTER` permissions on the table/view  so I doubt you have permissions to run it.  But you can probably ask for it to be done.  Problems like what you are describing are frequently caused by out of date statistics.